# Boolean Condition on Array with looping Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello i want to ask how i give boolean condition for some data which the data access from array. this is the code

```
for (var k in GexfJS.graph.edgeList) { 
    var _edge = GexfJS.graph.edgeList[k]
    if ( (_edge.source == _curre) && ( _edge.target != _nodeIndex) ) {
       var _node = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_edge.target]; 
       //action
    }
}
```

from the algorithm above, i want to give condition for each **_edge.target** which has given action it will be checked true by **check** (boolean condition)

example :

```
var check = false;
for (var k in GexfJS.graph.edgeList) { 
    var _edge = GexfJS.graph.edgeList[k]
    if ( (_edge.source == _curre) && ( _edge.target != _nodeIndex) && (check != true) ) {
        var _node = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_edge.target];
        //action
        check = true;
    }
}
```

the problem is, condition `check` it's can't stick with the `_edge.target`

Comment: replace "check = true;" with "check = true;break;", or use [].some or [].every

Comment: how can i use []? check = [] ?

then check(true) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not using Boolean condition but using an object,

```
if ( (_edg.target == _curra) && (_edg.source != _nodeIndex) && (_edg.target != _n)) {
                                    var _nod = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_edg.source];
                                    if(check[_nod.label] != true){
                                        if(_n != _nod){
                                        _str += '<li><div class="smallpill" style="background: ' + _nod.color.base +'"></div><a href="#" onmouseover="GexfJS.params.activeNode = ' + _edg.target + '" onclick="displayNode(' + _edg.target + ', true); return false;">' + _nod.label + 'b</a>' + ( GexfJS.params.showEdgeWeight && _edg.weight ? ' [' + _edg.weight + ']' : '') + '</li>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    check[_nod.label] = true; 
                                }
```

don't forget to write `var check={};`